# German book on introductory quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education

I'm looking for an originally German introduction to quantum mechanics. Is there such a canonical book used in German QM undergraduate courses?

Comment: Isn't this a bit too localized?

Comment: @Marek: I tend to agree, but it can be helpful to some. Actually, I think a general question about good books on QM in any language - probably community wiki and kept up to date - would be best.

Comment: Since Phys.SE is an English-speaking physics site, it seems off-topic to ask for literature in a specific language, so I'm closing the post. [Note that it is still OK (if someone asks about a topic X) to recommend non-English literature. Non-English literature might sometimes be the best resource.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a very good orignally german QM book is:

[Straumann: "Quantenmechanik: Ein Grundkurs über nichtrelativistische Quantentheorie"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540428887)

there is also a second volume:

[Straumann: "Relativistische Quantenfeldtheorie"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540229515)

Another good book is from [G. Grawert: Quantenmechanik](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3923944403)

You may also have a look at [Thirrings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3211825355) books about QM (it is mathematically more advanced).

I think Straumanns book is not "canonical".

Often used by students are the books by [Nolting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540688684) and Greiner.

From the experimental point of view you may have a look at [Demtröders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642039103) book.

Answer (score 3):

Walter Greiner's first part on Quantum Mechanics

[http://www.amazon.de/Quantummechanics-Introduction-Walter-Greiner/dp/3540674586](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540674586)